# StackExchange - Permissions For Answering And Viewing Questions

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, security

I'm trying to evaluate the StackExchange platform for an Ask the Professional type of implementation and there are a couple of things that may or may not be deal breakers in the analysis and I'm curious if they fit in at all...

1. Can permissions be used to limit which registered users can answer questions?
2. Can you require folks to be logged in to even view the questions?

Comment: Sounds like a bit of an odd choice for SE then... I mean, you wouldn't really need the voting or reputation systems at all. Why not just a forum?

Comment: @shog9: I've thought about that...  There are pros/cons for all of this...  The main thing I want to figure out though is if a "agent" answers a question, can we make it stick out.  If others answer questions, can we pull the agent one to the top?  The reputation could be good for us because it'll show the folks answering questions and asking them know their stuff...  May even be used to identify new agents in the long run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like one of those types of requests that would be better served for a branch off of an open sourced version of StackExchange, and not one that I would necessarily think would belong in a "main branch" StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would only work for a highly specialised implementation where there were already some acknowledged experts. But it is an interesting idea - particularly the idea of using the rep scores of the "non-experts" to identify future "experts".

You could (note could) have this semi-automatic when people hit a certain rep score.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that, for a price and perhaps some internal coding efforts, something like that seems possible. It seems like it could be worked into the SO framework, but I guess I wouldn't expect it to be initially support it.